# Using a variable inside of an http request

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, httprequest

I'm making an httpRequest using Parse, and what I want to do is have one aspect of the request take on the value of the `locationSearch` variable. When I attempt to do this as seen below, I get an error stating the following:

`Deploy failed with error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in main.js:322`

Line 322 that it refers to is this:

`'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),`

This means that inserting `locationSearch` right before that line is throwing it off, as it is expecting a key-value pair. The `locationSearch` variable is one of two possible key-value pairs, so I don't know how else to format the request.

I've considered using some sort of if statement, but I don't know how to format the syntax in a way that won't throw the request off. Is there any way I can do this?

Code:

```
for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {

        // ... later in your loop where you populate promises:
        var searchTerm = results[i].get('searchTerm');
        // add it to the array just like you add the promises:
        searchTerms.push(searchTerm);

        url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
        //push function containing criteria for every matchCenterItem into promises array
        promises.push((function() {

          locationSearch = results[i].get('itemLocation')

          var httpRequestPromise = Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: url,
            params: { 
              'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords',
              'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
              'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
              'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
              'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
              'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder' : 'BestMatch',
              'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' : '3',
              'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)' : 'New',
              'itemFilter(0).value(1)' : results[i].get('itemCondition'),
              'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value' : results[i].get('maxPrice'),
              'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue' : 'USD',
              'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value' : results[i].get('minPrice'),
              'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
               locationSearch,
              'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
            }
          });
          return httpRequestPromise
        })());
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is the line before (`locationSearch,`)

```
'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
locationSearch,
'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
```

This is not valid syntax. It must be something like:

```
'locationSearch': locationSearch,
```

or whatever would be the appropriate name for that property/field.

Also, in the following line, remove the trailing comma (','), as that's another syntax error.

```
'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
```